# How can one (reasonably) interpret this equality between the divergent $\zeta(1)$ and a division by $0$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

The Dirichlet eta function is defined as follows:

$$
\eta(s) = \left(1-2^{1-s}\right) \zeta(s).
$$

If one replaces $s$ by $1$ in the above formula, we get the apparent "absurdity":

$$
\zeta(1)=\frac{\eta(1)}{1-2^{0}}.
$$

The left hand side diverges, while the right hand side is a division by $0$.

How can one interpret such a result? Or is this case somehow handled differently in zeta function theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take the limit as $s$ tends to $1$, and use the fact that the Laurent expansion about $s = 1$ of $1 - 2^{1 - s}$ is
\[1 - e^{-(s - 1)\log 2} = 1 - 1 + (\log 2) (s - 1) + O((s - 1)^2),\]
while for $\zeta(s)$, we have that
\[\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s - 1} + \gamma_0 + O((s - 1)),\]
where $\gamma_0$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
So
\[\lim_{s \to 1} \eta(s) = \lim_{s \to 1} \left((\log 2) (s - 1) + O((s - 1)^2\right) \left(\frac{1}{s - 1} + \gamma_0 + O((s - 1))\right) = \log 2.\]

In the language of complex analysis, $s = 1$ is a removable singularity of $\eta(s)$: while $\eta(s)$ is not initially defined for $s = 1$, the function
\[\begin{cases}
\eta(s) & \text{if $\Re(s) > 0$, $s \neq 1$} \\\
\log 2 & \text{if $s = 1$}
\end{cases}\]
is holomorphic on the open half-plane $\Re(s) > 0$ and agrees with $\eta(s)$ when $s \neq 1$. This is called the holomorphic extension of $\eta(s)$.

Comment: Thank you. But then why does Wikipedia state that "it converges for any complex number having real part > 0", when clearly "1" is an exception?

Comment: The definition of $\eta(s)$ as the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} n^{-s}$ *does* converge when $s = 1$ (use the alternating series test, say).

Comment: In practice, one usually doesn't distinguish between a function with removable singularities and its holomorphic extension when working with such functions (unless you're in a first course in complex analysis, in which case it's important to understand the distinction).

Comment: OK thanks a lot!